# Socket does not throw an exception though he can’t connect

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception

I'm trying to connect a socket to an non-existent server, and I really don't understand why an exception is ***not*** being raised.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestSocket extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TestSocket";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BasicThread t = new BasicThread();
        t.start();
    }

    class BasicThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Before");
            try {
                new Socket("42.42.42.42", 12345);
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "After");
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with my own IP address while running Wireshark, and I first get `[SYN]` from Android to my computer and then `[RST, ACK]` from my computer to Android (because nothing is listening at this port), but I still do not get an exception on Android.

Also I’m testing on a physical phone (Nexus S), and I do have the internet permission in my Manifest.

Why aren't I getting an `Exception`?

**Edit:**

More precisely, the output I get is

```
D/TestSocket(17745): Before
D/TestSocket(17745): Connected
D/TestSocket(17745): After
```

(and not `Exception`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Socket constructor, it's thrown when the IP address of the host can't be determined, so I assume that because you aren't passing a hostname which needs resolution, a different exception would be getting thrown instead. I believe the exception actually comes from the URL class or such which does the resolution, and from nowhere else.

The connect(..) method *should* throw an exception but doesn't appear to, as you say.

Edit: apparently Android (some versions) doesn't work properly here, so it's probably a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6144. It doesn't look like the link refers to the emulator as I had thought.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting IOException to be thrown but this is not the case, nothing is thrown.

Comment: I expect it's swallowing the exception (I've had experience coding a simulated replacement for Socket, and the constructor really is a mess for exception handling). You could try creating a Socket just with the no-argument constructor and then calling connect explicitly and see if that gets you an exception. You could also check the connection status of the socket after the constructor and then throw your own IOException, or just fail :)

Comment: I tried (with the code of the answer of Joseph Earl) and I have exactly the same results.

Comment: Does "connected" get outputted?

Comment: Try outputting 'isConnected()' on the socket object and see what you get :)

Comment: Apparently the emulator is buggered for this. On a real device an exception should be thrown. http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg46905.html

Comment: I get `true`. This is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of things that can cause a socket connect to fail with an exception.

However, if the `SYN` message that the TCP protocol sends to start the connection process is

- blocked by a firewall,
- routed through a borked network, or
- routed to some endpoint that doesn't respond,

then TCP stack on the initiating machine will just retry, and retry.  If you have a connect timeout set, you will eventually get an exception, but it could take a long time.

---

The fact that it works on the Android emulator and not on the real device simply means that they are implemented or configured differently.  (For instance, they may have different default connect timeouts ... of the emulator may be designed to give connection refused in that scenario.)

The bottom line is that you need to make your code work on the real device.  Figure out the best way to make your device set a connect timeout, and check that that works when talking to the non-existent server.

Comment: The something does respond with a `[RST, ACK]` packet which (I guess) mean that nobody is listening here.  By the way, I tried with the emulator and I have a `ConnectException : Connection refused`. But this does not work on my phone.

Comment: The number of retries and the interval between them is determined by the OS implementation of TCP/IP, and Java doesn't provide a way either find out what these values are, or change them. But Java *should* raise an exception for an unconnected socket when the timeout expires It might be infinite, but then the consecutive code wouldn't get executed.

Comment: An RST (reset) response should be mapped to "connection refused" I think.

Answer (score -3):

Your try catch code doesn't catch IO Exceptions. Try something like this

```
try 
{
    // to get the ip address of the server by the name<br>
    InetAddress ip =InetAddress.getByName("example.com");

    sock= new Socket(ip,Server.PORT);
    ps= new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    ps.println(" Hi from client");
    DataInputStream is = new 
    DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    System.out.println(is.readLine());
}catch(SocketException e){
    System.out.println("SocketException " + e);
}catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("IOException " + e);
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. It catches `Exception` which is a base class of both `SocketException` and `IOException`. Answer is completely incorrect.