# Android client - Java server, Socket won't throw exception

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception

I'm trying to connect my Android APP to a Java server that I've made for it.
I have a problem, the server works good and the APP works fine too when connected to the server. 
The problem comes when I close the server and try to connect to it. The suppose is that the `Socket.connect()` would throw an exception that I would catch, but this exception is not thrown. 
I don't know what I'm doing bad, I paste my code here for you to read and maybe somone can help me.
 Thanks for all mates :D

Connection attributes:

```
static Socket s;
static DataOutputStream output;
static boolean connected;
```

The method who needs the connection:

```
public void enviarDatos(int r, int g, int b){

    connect();
    if(connected){
        panel.setText(panel.getText() + "\nEnviando datos...");
        try {
            output.writeUTF(r + "," + g + "," + b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            panel.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        disconnect();
    } 
}
```

The methods to connect and disconnect are there:

```
public void connect(){
    try {
        s = new Socket();
        int timeout = 1000;
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT), timeout);
        output = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        connected = true;
        panel.setText("Conexion exitosa.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        connected = false;
        panel.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void disconnect(){
    try{
        output.close();
        s.close();
        connected = false;
    } catch(Exception e){
        panel.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you executing that in a separate thread? If it is so, then you can't touch the panel view inside the thread. If it is not, then the main UI does not allow you to do any networking. But you should get an exception any ways. Instead of `panel.setText` use `e.printStackTrace()` inside the catch statement.

Comment: No, that's the same thread.
When I turn on the server, it works fine, the server receive the text, and all works good, the problem is when I turn off the server. It does the same, like the server is on.
The thing is that it never reaches the catch, because no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `connect()` method is different from the one you posted in the large code block where you present both the methods. It's pretty unclear which one you are using to connect. Try adding the `int timeout` parameter to the `connect()` like this:

```
int timeout = 1000; // 1s timeout
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT), timeout);
```

This should make `connect` throw an `IOException` after the timeout expires.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copy-pasted it bad :P The method that should be in the first block is not `connect()` but `enviarDatos(int r, int g, int b)`.<br> Even so, I will try it.

Comment: It keeps doing the same -.-
Maybe my SDK has a bug? I update it everyday, but I don't know... 
The socket don't throw any exception.

Comment: Have you checked that the thread is blocked by `s.connect(...)`, and if so, how long? Try surrounding the method call with `Log.i(...)` and check Logcat for what actually happens. Does the call block for 1000ms as specified or infinity?

Comment: Ok, now it works in the AVD, but in my mobile phone it keeps doing the same thing.. Any idea?
Edit: I think it works in the AVD because the server is hosted in the same PC as the AVD and they share the IP..

Comment: What version is your phone? Maybe the Socket class behaves differently in early versions.. Try this: make an s.isConnected() call after the connect and check wether the Socket assumes it's connected or not.

Comment: I have Android 2.3.6, and my project build with minimum SDK 9, which is 2.2... It keeps doing it bad -.-
Changed that I did (after `s.connect(...);`:
`if(s.isConnected()){ connected = true; panel.setText("Conexion exitosa."); } else { s.close(); panel.setText("Error: Cannot connect."); }`

Comment: I'm typing from my phone now, so i can't format the code parts at the moment... Anyway, is s.isConnected() still returning true? I did some research, and it seems you're not the only one having similar problems.. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718450/socket-does-not-throw-an-exception-though-he-cant-connect. Try running the app on another device and see if the problem persists

Answer (score -1):

I see one potential issue in "disconnect". I think you're trying to close the socket when the output stream is still opened. In this case, the socket may not close properly which may cause issues in reopening. Although you should see an exception being thrown during closing.

In disconnect(), can you try closing output first before closing the socket?

```
public void disconnect(){
    try{
        output.close();
        s.close();
        connected = false;
    } catch(Exception e){
        panel.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I don't have the context of this problem, but that's one potential issue I saw. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I've tried it, and it still didn't work.. I don't know what is wrong with my code -.-
It always say: _"Conexion exitosa."_, even if the server is shut down.

Comment: Can you try printing the exception to logcat (using Log.d), instead of UI view? It helps eliminating the issue in UI update. Hopefully we will see the exception in logcat.

Comment: Now it works in the AVD, but in my mobile phone it still didn't throw the exception. I think it works in the AVD because it is the same IP as my PC, where the server is running in.
Any idea?

Comment: Closing either the socket or its input stream or output stream closes everything. The problem described in this answer is completely imaginary.

Comment: Ok ... sounds like your device is unable to see the server. Are they on the same network? I'm not sure about your network configuration. Can you try putting both the PC server and Android device on the same wifi network? After putting them both on the same wifi network, double check the IP of the server. Then try to connect to server from your device.

Comment: My device can see the server, because when the server is on, it connects correctly, and sends well the message. The problem is when the server is off, my device ignores it, and keeps saying that the connection was established and the message was sent, and that's impossible, the problem, I think, is that no exception is thrown, I don't know why... The server and the client work well together when the server is on, but when its off, the client ignores it.